# How can I correctly run a timed process in my app the will start on stop when the application is in use or in the background?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an application that starts up and runs a background check of the database every minute. Below is the code for this.

I'm getting what I think is a memory leak and am looking at all areas of the code that loop.

Is there any possibility that this code could be left in a looping state and contribute to a memory leak or is the way the onSleep and onResume coded a 100% sure way to correctly stop and start the timer loop?

Note that I only want the timed part of the code to run once a minute when the application is being used and in the foreground.

```
namespace Japanese
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {

        private static Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainPage = new Japanese.MainPage();
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            App.DB.InitData();

            if (!stopWatch.IsRunning) 
                stopWatch.Start();

            Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1), () =>
            {
                if (stopWatch.IsRunning && stopWatch.Elapsed.Minutes >= defaultTimespan)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Checking database");
                    PointChecker.CheckScore();
                    stopWatch.Restart();
                }
                return true;
            });
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            stopWatch.Reset();
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            stopWatch.Start();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to stop a timer which you start by Device.StartTimer. Why you are using stopwatch at all?

Comment: Despite not clear for me design using timer and stopwatch I don't see anything that can cause memory leak besides PointChecker.CheckScore. I ran this for an hour and it kept running

Comment: When you close the app on iOS this will no longer run. Is that ok for your application? I think that you should read this [forum post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/11939/run-background-task-every-x-amount-of-time)  about background tasks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The App class is the class that represents the cross-platform mobile application, it is running even your "MainPage" was not, so i think you need to use `OnAppearing` and `OnDisappearing` methods in your main page (a `:ContentPage`).

Maybe something like :

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
   stopWatch.Start();
   base.OnAppearing();
}
```

and,

```
protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
 stopWatch.Reset();
 base.OnDisappearing();
}
```

I hope that helps,
Mabrouk.